# No Such Element Exception in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have developed a whole application using normal **HTML** and **CSS**.
Normal record and play using **SELENIUM** **IDE** is working **perfectly** **fine**, but when we are writing a script using **Selenium** **WebDriver** it is throwing the error as "**NoSuchElementException**".

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class olp {

    WebDriver driver = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://10.67.89.15/olp/index.html");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='uname']")).sendKeys("user_sam");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pas']")).sendKeys("special26");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='loginb']")).click();      
    }

}
```

**This is the code which i have written.**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="uname">User Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="name" placeholder="Enter User Name" value="">
    <div id="uerror" class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pas">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="pas" placeholder="Enter password" value="">
  <div id="perror" class="error"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="loginb" >SIGN IN</button>
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='uname']")).sendKeys("user_sam"); this line while entering data in username field.

Comment: Is the log in form is in popup?

Comment: You should implement explicit or implicit wait for user input element

Comment: @guy the login form is not in popup.

Comment: @sandeepraulo Try the explicit wait in my answer.

Comment: @guy i tried with implicitwait...actually the thing is for some instance it is recognizing the elements but for some it is giving the error.

Comment: @sandeepraulo implicit wait means that the driver waiting until the element exist in the DOM. that doesn't mean you can interact  with it. With explicit wait and  Expected Conditions the driver is waiting until you can interact with the element.